# ARPC Verification Failure on POS

Tags: emv, pos

We are successfully processing transactions and verifying ARQC data using KW command on a Thales 9000 HSM however the POS is failing to verify ARPC with ISO Error Code Z1.
Below is our response data. We have been doing some research online and consulting industry experts but no luck.

Tag 8A - 00
Tag 91 - FEA27497000000000000000000000000
Tag 9F36 - 006C

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: as Michael suggested, post the relevant logs. Request logs with all fields preferably from POS itself( even though I do not suspect the issue is in the request since ARQC is validated), request/response from HSM, and the response which is received at POS. Have you checked the ARC sent to POS is as expected ?

Answer (score 1):

ARPC is a cryptographically calculated value. What you have here seems too low on entropy to be the result of such calculation.

Are you sure you have the request and response to HSM right? It does not seem like it. You might be interpreting the response incorrectly, but you might want to add the log showing what you have sent to and received from HSM.